# Error in a JavaScript comment line

Tags: javascript

When i write JavaScript comments with stressed vowels at the end like this:

```
// Multiselección
var mul = true;
```

The browser "changes" code and write in one line:

```
// Multiselecci           var mul = true;
```

and writes the second line in the same line the comment

Any idea about what is happening?

Thank you

Comment: What is `navigator interprets the next code`?  is the problem with IDEs?

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan I suppose that he means the browser "changes" the second line to a comment

Comment: I think you should avoid non UTF-7 characters in a JS file as it may lead to unpredicted results as you can see

Comment: remove the comment and try again what happen?

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan I didn't explain well, i've changed the question

Comment: what is the encoding of your file? What's the "end of line" character set to?

Comment: try use `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the file where you call JS file, but it's better if you avoid these characters